# How to get midi file type (0/1/2) in java?

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi

I am parsing a MIDI file using:

```
Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(paFile);
```

How do I distinguish the SMF file type? I have not found any method returning it.
Is it safe to assume, that sequence with only one track is type 0 and with multiple tracks type 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to know how the tracks in a type 2 file are to be handled in the general case, and the only difference between type 0 and 1 files is the allowed number of tracks.
Therefore, the `Sequence` does not bother to remember the file type.

If you really want to know the file type, you have to read it directly from the file with [MidiSystem.getMidiFileFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#getMidiFileFormat%28java.io.File%29).